# How to add a row to every group with pandas groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I wish to add a new row in the first line within each group, my raw dataframe is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': ['James', 'James', 'James','Max', 'Max', 'Max', 'Max','Park','Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom','Wong'],
    'From_num': [78, 420, 'Started', 298, 36, 298, 'Started', 'Started', 60, 520, 99, 'Started', 'Started'],
    'To_num': [96, 78, 420, 36, 78, 36, 298, 311, 150, 520, 78, 99, 39],
    'Date': ['2020-05-12', '2020-02-02', '2019-06-18',
             '2019-06-20', '2019-01-30', '2018-10-23',
             '2018-08-29', '2020-05-21', '2019-11-22',
             '2019-08-26', '2018-12-11', '2018-10-09', '2019-02-01']})
```

it is like this:

```
      ID From_num  To_num        Date
0   James       78      96  2020-05-12
1   James      420      78  2020-02-02
2   James  Started     420  2019-06-18
3     Max      298      36  2019-06-20
4     Max       36      78  2019-01-30
5     Max      298      36  2018-10-23
6     Max  Started     298  2018-08-29
7    Park  Started     311  2020-05-21
8     Tom       60     150  2019-11-22
9     Tom      520     520  2019-08-26
10    Tom       99      78  2018-12-11
11    Tom  Started      99  2018-10-09
12   Wong  Started      39  2019-02-01
```

For each person ('ID'), I wish to create a new duplicate row on the first row within each group ('ID'), the values for the created row in column'ID', 'From_num' and 'To_num' should be the same as the previous first row, but the 'Date' value is the old 1st row's Date plus one day e.g. for James, the newly created row values is: 'James' '78' '96' '2020-05-13', same as the rest data, so my expected result is:

```
       ID From_num  To_num        Date
0   James       78      96  2020-05-13  # row added, Date + 1
1   James       78      96  2020-05-12
2   James      420      78  2020-02-02
3   James  Started     420  2019-06-18
4     Max      298      36  2019-06-21  # row added, Date + 1
5     Max      298      36  2019-06-20
6     Max       36      78  2019-01-30
7     Max      298      36  2018-10-23
8     Max  Started     298  2018-08-29
9    Park  Started     311  2020-05-22  # Row added, Date + 1
10   Park  Started     311  2020-05-21
11    Tom       60     150  2019-11-23  # Row added, Date + 1
12    Tom       60     150  2019-11-22
13    Tom      520     520  2019-08-26
14    Tom       99      78  2018-12-11
15    Tom  Started      99  2018-10-09
16   Wong  Started      39  2019-02-02  # Row added Date + 1
17   Wong  Started      39  2019-02-01
```

I wrote some loop conditions but quite slow, If you have any good ideas, please help. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try `groupby.apply` here. We'll append a row to each group at the start, like this:

```
def augment_group(group):
    first_row = group.iloc[[0]]
    first_row['Date'] += pd.Timedelta(days=1) 
    return first_row.append(group)

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce')
(df.groupby('ID', as_index=False, group_keys=False)
   .apply(augment_group)
   .reset_index(drop=True))

       ID From_num  To_num       Date
0   James       78      96 2020-05-13
1   James       78      96 2020-05-12
2   James      420      78 2020-02-02
3   James  Started     420 2019-06-18
4     Max      298      36 2019-06-21
5     Max      298      36 2019-06-20
6     Max       36      78 2019-01-30
7     Max      298      36 2018-10-23
8     Max  Started     298 2018-08-29
9    Park  Started     311 2020-05-22
10   Park  Started     311 2020-05-21
11    Tom       60     150 2019-11-23
12    Tom       60     150 2019-11-22
13    Tom      520     520 2019-08-26
14    Tom       99      78 2018-12-11
15    Tom  Started      99 2018-10-09
16   Wong  Started      39 2019-02-02
17   Wong  Started      39 2019-02-01
```

Although I agree with @Joran Beasley in the comments that this feels like somewhat of an XY problem. Perhaps try clarifying the problem you're trying to solve, instead of asking how to implement what you think is the solution to your issue?

Comment: Thanks @cs95 for your answer, as in my actual case it is a part for tracing the missing records, after that I also need to modify the rest records of the data, and that is something I can deal with, but this question makes me quite productive. Many thanks for the answer

Comment: @XaviorL I see... are you working together with the OP on this task?

Comment: Yes, we are new members in the same team. Thank you

Comment: @XaviorL It is not uncommon for a team representative to ask questions that the rest of the team are watching. However a small word of advice is to take care to not have your whole team upvote your teammate's question. That constitutes serial/targeted upvoting which is discouraged. Not accusing you in any way of this, just wanted to share some advice as I've seen it happen all too many times before. Cheers and glad to have helped!

Comment: Oh sorry @cs95, we are new graduates mates in the same team, got the new roles together. Did not realize it may cause this issue, will delete this Qs now

Comment: @XaviorL Don't delete the question please, we would not want your efforts on the question and my efforts on the answer to be in vain ;-) Future readers may benefit from this question. This is just some advice for the future.